# Touch screen is dead and inputs are dead: How to access my damaged tablet data?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, tablet

I own a tablet PC ([Haier Y11b](http://www.haier.com/pk/products/pc/Tablet_PC/y11b.shtml)) which can be used as standalone tablet while bottom part is detached. And as a laptop when bottom part is connected. Upper part consists of a touchscreen, SSD, speakers, headphone jack, MicroSD slot and no USB ports. Bottom part consists of a keyboard, trackpad, additional hard-disk and USB-ports in it.

I accidentally dropped it while using it in tablet mode and its touch and bottom connector are not working. I cannot connect any external USB mouse/keyboard as there are no USB-ports in upper part. Moreover since touch is also broken, I cannot give any inputs to the tablet. I can only confirm it is ON as when I press power button, lockscreen shows up. Only other inputs I can give it are volume buttons that are located on side adjacent to power button.

There is some important data in SSD which I need to access. I cannot pull the SSD out as I've turned on the bit-locker for SSD therefore it won't work in some other PC. I don't want to repair this thing since I'm going to buy a new one. I just want to access the data.

It's running latest version of Windows 10. I know its PIN/Password, my phone is paired with it via bluetooth and tablet is connected  to my home WiFi if any of it helps.

Is it possible to access my data that is stored in SSD without dissembling/repairing through possibly some software solution?

Comment: What's the model?  What's the issue with removing the SSD to either plug it in on another machine or use an adapter to connect it?  How usable is the tablet in its current condition?

Comment: Tablet is'nt any usable

Comment: @User5 What is the exact make and model of the tablet?

Comment: Do you have a copy of the BitLocker recovery key?

Comment: Of course not... Otherwise what's the point of mentioning that in explicit. But now I've learned my lesson and will have a copy from now on

Comment: I ask because lots of people forget that they had made a backup (often a printout), as is usually recommended. Better to ask and confirm than to miss the easy option.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to presume it's booting even if you can't see it is, and that it's connected on your wireless network, hopefully with network shares enabled.

From another machine on the same network, you want to:

1. Find out the IP the tablet is picking up, you maybe able to do this via your routers admin, or even by identifying the tablet via the hostname and pinging it from another machine on your network. You might need to use a tool like angry IP scanner (https://angryip.org/download/#windows)
2. In a file explorer window (not internet explorer) try to go to \IP ADDRESS\c$ where 'IP ADDRESS' is the ip address of the tablet. If you've enabled file and printer sharing (enabled automatically when you selected 'home' network upon attaching to the wifi then you can hopefully access the storage from this - You'll need to have set a user with a password on the tablet.
3. (Alt) Try remote desktop, or something like dameware to remote onto the tablet.

Comment: Network sharing wasn't enabled on my tablet 

Comment: Ok - how about remote desktop? I'm unsure if it needs enabling or not.

Comment: It does need enabling there's a switch in system's settings in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

When my phone screen was broken, i bought a type c adapter. connected to external screen and mouse as well. using mouse can easily works.
[image: Google image]